# Encode a movie with Unicode filename in Windows using Popen

Tags: ruby, unicode, ffmpeg, popen

I want to encode a movie through IO.popen by ruby(1.9.3) in windows 7.
If the file name contains only ascii strings, encoding proceed normally.
But with unicode filename the script returns "No such file or directory" error.
Like following code.

```
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
command = "ffmpeg -i ü.rm"
IO.popen(command){|pipe|
  pipe.each{|line|
    p line
  }
}
```

I couldn't find whether the problem causes by ffmpeg or ruby.
How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't use UTF-8 encoding. Ruby send the byte sequence of the Unicode filename to the file system directly, and of course the file system won't recognize UTF-8 sequences. It seems newer version of Ruby has fixed this issue. (I'm not sure. I'm using 1.9.2p290 and it's still there.)

You need to convert the UTF-8 filename to the encoding your Windows uses.

```rb
# coding: utf-8
code_page = "cp#{`chcp`.chomp[/\d+$/]}"   # detect code page automatically.
command = "ffmpeg -i ü.rm".encode(code_page)
IO.popen(command) do |pipe|
  pipe.each do |line|
    p line
  end
end
```

Another way is to save your script with the same encoding Windows uses. And don't forget to update the encoding declaration. For example, I'm using Simplified Chinese Windows and it uses GBK(CP936) as default encoding:

```rb
# coding: GBK
# save this file in GBK
command = "ffmpeg -i ü.rm"
IO.popen(command) do |pipe|
  pipe.each do |line|
    p line
  end
end
```

BTW, by convention, it is suggested to use `do...end` for multi-line code blocks rather than `{...}`, unless in special cases.

**UPDATE**:

The underlying filesystem NTFS uses UTF-16 for file name encoding. So `가` is a valid filename character. However, GBK isn't able to encode `가`, and so as to CP932 in your Japanese Windows. So you cannot send that specific filename to your `cmd.exe` and it isn't likely you can process that file with `IO.popen`. For CP932 compatible filenames, the encoding approach provided above works fine. For those filenames not compatible with CP932, it might be better to modify your filenames to a compatible one.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i'm using Japanese, Korean and German in Japanese Windows and sometimes I rename a file like "あ가ü.avi". So it must be UTF8. And with cmd.exe I can encode the file without problem.

Comment: At first I got a error messege:
`code_page = "cp#{\`chcp\`.chomp[/\d+$/]}"`
So I set code page directly `code_page="cp932"` (I checked by cmd.exe.)
then I got the error :
`encode': U+00FC from UTF-8 to Windows-31J +(Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`
According to wikipedia, GBK includes Japanese and Korean characters.
I think that's why you can run this code without error.

Comment: @Tetsu check the update, although no workable solution provided, sorry

Comment: Thanks anyway! I know now that it's impossible to send unicode file name properly in windows. :)